# Where (exactly) is the call stack?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, ld, callstack

How can I find the address bounds of the call stack at runtime (via some symbol or register)?  I'm using `nm` and `readelf` to pick through my symbols and I'm not finding one.  In the case of registers, it seems I'm limited to the current frame's base and stack pointers and not the starting address.

I'd like to shy away from answers that involve parsing `/proc/pid/maps` - I always feel awkward parsing text for a systems-related problem.  I'm using `g++` on `Linux x86/x86_64`.

**EDIT:** Can I use the `x86` segment register `SS` to calculate it?

Comment: Hrm, I see now that you're after something different than most people who ask the question (often curiosity or homework :) -- are you running in userspace or kernelspace? Is modifying the ELF loader fair game? Is this a process introspecting itself or an external process doing the inspecting?

Comment: Heh, yeah.  I'm mocking up a SDSM system.  I'm running in userspace, am able to modify the ELF loader, and have the master process inspecting itself with `Dyninst` or global symbols.

Comment: Hah; with this new information I went hunting into the eglibc sources to try to find the loader's source, which I assumed would set up the stack. I found the following comment in `dl-execstack.c`: _There is no portable way to know the bounds of the initial thread's stack so as to `mprotect` it._ That doesn't sound so good. :(

Comment: There is rain on my parade, now.  That is *exactly* what I'm trying to do.  Thanks, though. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/proc/pid/maps` file on Linux provides some information on a process's memory mappings:

```
$ cat /proc/self/maps 
00400000-0040b000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 709349                             /bin/cat
0060a000-0060b000 r--p 0000a000 08:03 709349                             /bin/cat
0060b000-0060c000 rw-p 0000b000 08:03 709349                             /bin/cat
00a2d000-00a4e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f6fdf418000-7f6fdf6bd000 r--p 00000000 08:03 489885                     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
...
7fff4669e000-7fff466bf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff467ff000-7fff46800000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

The `pmap(1)` command formats this information into a display that I find more pleasing:

```
$ pmap $$
11680:   bash
0000000000400000    896K r-x--  /bin/bash
...
00007ff31ae2d000      8K rw---  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
00007fff66dd2000    132K rw---    [ stack ]
00007fff66dff000      4K r-x--    [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000      4K r-x--    [ anon ]
 total            29336K
```

Incidentally, in the eglibc source file `dl-execstack.c`, I found the following comment: *There is no portable way to know the bounds of the initial thread's stack so as to `mprotect` it.* This probably means the best mechanism is to parse the `/proc/pid/maps` files, even though I think we're all agreed it is tacky.

Comment: Accepted for comment in on question!

Answer (score 1):

The *current* stack pointer is available in the `esp` register. However, since stacks are allocated at runtime (because there might be multiple threads), you will have to dive into the private data of your runtime library to find out where the bounds of the current stack are.

Comment: When I need this code executed there is just a single process. I want the bottom address of the stack (not `esp`).  If I could know what `esp` was before the `.init` code is called, that would work! =)

Comment: Since the stack goes downwise, `esp` is the bottom address (but you want the top). Why do you need the bounds of the stack?

Comment: @asaelr: Process migration experiment.  I need to duplicate address spaces to `n` processes.  Only a single process *runs* at a time, but at synchronization points, process state is synchronized.  Right now, I'm using heuristics to detect stack bounds.

Comment: @sholsapp: Isn't that what `fork()` does ?

Answer (score 1):

The closest you'll get is `/proc/self/maps`, but even that's not going to make it easy if your program is multi-threaded. You probably should just accept that this is not something you can do in C. It would help if we knew what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for an object file to contain the address of call stack. The call stack is been allocated by the OP after it load a runnable file.

Usually, `rsp` (or `esp`, or whatever you have in your platform) contain the address of the bottom of the call stack. Which mean, it should differ when you call a function (and maybe even when you declare a variable).